# Decode json response in android

Tags: android, json

I need to decode a json response sent from php in android.

---

***JSON Response***

> {"VehicleNumber":"1234FB14","Make":"BMW","Model":"X5","Type":"Car","Color":"Black","EngineCapacity":"1800cc","Fuel":"Diesel","DateOfReg":"31-Dec-2013","OwnerNIC":"B1234567890123","serviceArray":[[{"VehicleNumber":"1234FB14","DateOfService":"07-march-2014","Mileage":"1800","Description":"tponggshmbch"}],[{"VehicleNumber":"1234FB14","DateOfService":"07-march-2014","Mileage":"1900","Description":"tponggshmbch"}]]}

---

The response consists of values for their respective keys and I can retrieve these value by just calling getString(key) in java. `{key:value,2D Array[][]}`

The problem is that I can't decode the 2D Array being passed here. I get it in a string format in java and if I display it in my android app I can view this:

> [[{"VehicleNumber":"1234FB14","DateOfService":"07-march-2014","Mileage":"1800","Description":"tponggshmbch"}],[{"VehicleNumber":"1234FB14","DateOfService":"07-march-2014","Mileage":"1900","Description":"tponggshmbch"}]]

But i need to retrieve all the value from the 2D array.
Any help please.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

Comment: Thanks Anthony...il try to use the JsonReader..

Answer (score 0):

If Your json is quite big I recommend using `gson` or `Jackson` libraries.

Comment: @pixel..this was just few lines mate..there are many more to retrieve. I just need to be able to decode the individual multidimentional arrays.